# How to get same Midterm two or more times for same subject?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 3 tables likes Student,Subject,and Midterm tables.
Student TABLE contains

```
studid Firstname lastname Class

1      A       R        12A
2      B       S        12A
3      C       T        12A
4      D       U        12A
5      E       V        12B
```

SUBJECT TABLE CONTAINS

```
subid subname
  1     maths
  2     science
  3     english
```

MIDTERM TABLE CONTAINS

```
studid subid marks examdate
1        1    100  2014-09-24
1        2     92  2014-09-25
1        2     92  2014-09-26
2        1     74  2014-09-24
2        2     78  2014-09-26
2        3     73  2014-09-26
3        1     90  2014-09-24
3        2     84  2014-09-25
3        2     92  2014-09-25
5        1     87  2014-09-24
4        2     79  2014-09-24
4        3     90  2014-09-26
```

In this I want to list all the students who have taken same midterm 2 or more times for the same subject.required o/p is Firstname, lastname, no.of attempts

This is my query:

```
select studid,SubID
FROM [StudentDetails].[dbo].[MidTermTable]
group by StudID,SubID having COUNT(subid)>1
```

Comment: " i want ..." - then make an attempt.

Comment: I couldn't understand what your are saying@Mitch Wheat

Comment: Means what have you tried so far? Paste it in your question.

Comment: i used this query 
  select studid,SubID FROM [StudentDetails].[dbo].[MidTermTable] 
  group by StudID,SubID having COUNT(subid)>1 
but i dont know how to use it in join. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

**Create sample data**

```
DECLARE @Student TABLE (studid INT, Firstname VARCHAR(10), lastname VARCHAR(10), Class VARCHAR(10))

INSERT @Student
SELECT 1,      'A',       'R',        '12A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,      'B',       'S',        '12A' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,      'C',       'T',        '12A' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,      'D',       'U',        '12A' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,      'E',       'V',        '12B'

DECLARE @subject TABLE(subid INT, subname VARCHAR(10))

INSERT @subject
SELECT  1,     'maths' UNION ALL
SELECT  2,     'science' UNION ALL
SELECT  3,     'english'

DECLARE @Midterm TABLE (studid INT, subid INT, marks INT, examdate DATE)

INSERT @Midterm
SELECT 1,        1,    100,  '2014-09-24' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,        2,     92,  '2014-09-25' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,        2,     92,  '2014-09-26' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,        1,     74,  '2014-09-24' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,        2,     78,  '2014-09-26' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,        3,     73,  '2014-09-26' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,        1,     90,  '2014-09-24' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,        2,     84,  '2014-09-25' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,        2,     92,  '2014-09-25' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,        1,     87,  '2014-09-24' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,        2,     79,  '2014-09-24' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,        3,     90,  '2014-09-26'
```

**Query:** One way to do that is using a window function

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT  Firstname
            ,lastname
            ,m.subid
            ,examdate
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.studid, m.subid ORDER BY s.studid, m.subid) AS Rn
    FROM @Student AS s
    INNER JOIN @Midterm AS m ON m.studid = s.studid
    INNER JOIN @subject AS sj ON sj.subid = m.subid
)
SELECT  Firstname
        ,lastname
        ,MAX(Rn) AS [Number of attempts]
FROM C
WHERE Rn > 1
GROUP BY Firstname, lastname
```

**Output**

```
Firstname   lastname    Number of attempts
A           R           2
C           T           2
```

I suggest you to study about [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: can anyone tell how rownumber works with simple example

Comment: without using CTE how can i write it in subquery

Comment: I tried this query but it shows error

select firstname,lastname,
(select a.subname,b.studid from [StudentDetails].dbo.SubjectTable a
inner join [StudentDetails].[dbo].[MidTermTable] b on a.SubID=b.SubID
group by a.subname,b.studid having COUNT(b.SubID)>1) As NumOfAttempts
from [StudentDetails].dbo.StudentTable

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Student].Firstname, [Student].Firstname, count(*)
  FROM [MidTermTable] 
  JOIN [Student]
    on [Student].[studid] = [MidTermTable],[Student].
 group by [Student].Firstname, [Student].Firstname, SubID 
having COUNT(*) > 1
```